# Why does Slack limit the number of contacts in my sidebar's direct messages section?

Tags: slack

Slack seems to limit the number of contacts shown in my sidebar's direct messages section to 10 or 11 contacts. If I start a direct message with somebody new, another conversation is removed from the sidebar.

I'm now displaying "All my channels and DM". I tried the other sidebar options, but they don't seem to do what I want.

My colleagues don't have this behavior. Is there a way to disable it or set another limit?

Comment: yes! this is soooooo annoying

Comment: Still an issue 6 months later

Comment: This is one of the "Features" I hate the most in Slack. Sure I can Ctrl+k to get the person I'm looking for, but I'd rather see them along side with their online status. I don't mind if I have to scroll more for this.

Comment: What do you mean you're now displaying "All my channels and DM"?

Comment: @MichaelTerry it's how it's labelled in Slack's options (or at least was when I posted the question, haven't checked since)

Comment: I see. I have "Everything" checked off in preferences, and it still caps my DM list in the sidebar.

Comment: Still an issue 4 years later

Answer (score 41):

--Update. On desktop, you can STAR a message by right clicking the conversation and clicking "Star conversation". On mobile, open the conversation, and then tap the "View Details" button at the top. You'll then see the STAR icon on the top right.

Open a direct message and STAR it to keep it showing on the sidebar. This is very useful because it does remove any duplicates that would show up in the direct messages part of the sidebar, so you still have plenty of space.

Comment: This confused me for a long time. I tried to star a DM from one of my colleagues and nothing happened. I didn't notice you could star the user themselves underneath their name in the DM pane.

Comment: This is a good temporary fix, although I still think Slack should let you adjust how many DM's you want to display under Direct Messages.

Comment: Seems like a legit fix to me. Anything you don't want to go away, you just star.

Comment: OK then.... how do I automatically star every conversation so they don't get lost? You can't expect users like me (with memory of a fish) to remember all conversations. Some things take a few days/weeks to resolve. Is there at least a history??

Comment: @JaimeEspinosa you can click the All DMs button to see recent threads. It's in the left side bar above your starred threads.

Comment: I do not see any star icons in the desktop version of Slack.

Comment: @S.V The UI in Slack has changed a little bit, so I updated my answer.

Comment: To get a DM to show in the sidebar without sending a message to it (so that you can then star or move it to a new section), you have to use the Ctrl/Cmd-K switcher shortcut. The + button next to DMs and the search bar in the All DMs pane don't work for this.

Answer (score 9):

You can "Star" direct messages and or Channels.
In the Direct messages to Person-A type "/star " and Slack will create a new heading group called "Starred" (if it doesn't already exist), and place the 
Person-A direct message under it. Same works for Channels. 
This means that you can stop worrying about Direct Messages for Person-A dropping off the Direct Messages list, as they will now stay permanently under the "Starred" heading.

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining HOW to do this. In the past I starred a message before, but it didn't do anything. Sending a person a "/star" as message fixes the issue, plus it's only visible to you.

Comment: WTF, I don't want to star shit. I can afford to scroll and/or possibly reorganize and pull more important things up if I need to. Shit diseappearing is seriously kind of bad design. If you have a group chat going on they will disappear and you have to re-add all to it. Why can't they just let people scroll and organize as they see fit.

Answer (score 5):

Use Slack's New Sidebar Editor.
Create a new "Direct Messages" Section, and move your team / DMs into that new section.

Answer (score -3):

Try to add contacts from plus sign before "DIRECT MESSAGES". It solved problem for me.